# iostreams - Print `wchar_t` or `charXX_t` value as a character

Tags: c++, iostream, widechar

If you feed a `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t` value to a narrow ostream, it will print the numeric value of the code point.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    cout << 'x' << L'x' << u'x' << U'x' << '\n';
}
```

prints `x120120120`.  This is because there is an `operator<<` for the specific combination of `basic_ostream` with its `charT`, but there aren't analogous operators for the other character types, so they get silently converted to `int` and printed that way.  Similarly, non-narrow string literals (`L"x"`, `u"x"`, `U"X"`) will be silently converted to `void*` and printed as the pointer value, and non-narrow string *objects* (`wstring`, `u16string`, `u32string`) won't even compile.

So, the question:  What is the least awful way to print a `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t` value on a narrow ostream, *as the character*, rather than as the numeric value of the codepoint?  It should correctly convert *all* codepoints that are representable in the encoding of the ostream, to that encoding, and should report an error when the codepoint is not representable.  (For instance, given `u'…'` and a UTF-8 ostream, the three-byte sequence 0xE2 0x80 0xA6 should be written to the stream; but given `u'â'` and a KOI8-R ostream, an error should be reported.)

Similarly, how can one print a non-narrow C-string or string object on a narrow ostream, converting to the output encoding?

If this can't be done within ISO C++11, I'll take platform-specific answers.

(Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106981/unicode-literal-how-do-this-even-make-sense/41107165#41107165).)

Comment: In short, you have to either 1) use a wide ostream, or 2) convert the wide character data to the narrow encoding yourself (which is a potentially lossy conversion). An ostream cannot do that conversion for you. Look at [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert), or use a library like [ICONV](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, there is no `operator<<(std::ostream&, const wchar_t)` for a narrow ostream. If you want to use the syntax you can however teach `ostream` how to do with `wchar`s so that that routine is picked as a better overload that the one requiring a conversion to an integer first.

If you're feeling adventurous:

```
namespace std {
  ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, wchar_t wc) {
    if(unsigned(wc) < 256) // or another upper bound
      return os << (unsigned char)wc;
    else
      throw your_favourite_exception; // or handle the error in some other way
  }
}
```

Otherwise, make a simple `struct` that transparently encompasses a `wchar_t` and has a custom `friend operator<<` and convert your wide characters to that before outputting them.

**Edit:** To make an on-the-fly conversion to and from the locale, you can use the functions from [`<cwchar>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cwchar), like:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, wchar_t wc) {
    std::mbstate_t state{};
    std::string mb(MB_CUR_MAX, '\0');
    size_t ret = std::wcrtomb(&mb[0], wc, &state);
    if(ret == static_cast<std::size_t>(-1))
        deal_with_the_error();
    return os << mb;
}
```

Don't forget to set your locale to the system default:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
std::cout << L'ŭ';
```

Comment: This does not convert the value to the narrow output encoding.  That's essential, and it's also the piece that I don't already know how to do.

Comment: @zwol How else would you like to convert a wide character than accepting it if it's within ASCII and rejecting otherwise? You'd then need to be specific, e.g., removing accents or something.

Comment: Your example uses an 'x' which passes this (for the `L'x'`, you'd need to do the same for the other types) so I assumed that's what you're after.

Comment: It should, for instance, convert L"…" to the three-byte sequence 0xE2 0x80 0xA6 when the narrow output encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I wanted something that could handle _all_ characters supported by the narrow output encoding, not just ASCII.

Comment: I see! I thought the output encoding was ASCII. `iconv` is not hard to use, I'll try to work it in.

Comment: @zwol Please see updated, there was a better way after all.